# Group by specific column in PostgreSQL

Tags: group-by, postgresql-9.4

I trying to get a count of person depending on the org_id.

Let's say I have 10 people in my people coming in from different organization.

I want to count no of people working in separate with each record listed.

Please click here on  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/00a2c2/2) link to get what exactly I am trying to do.

Postgres version 9.4

Below are my table records:

```
id  person_name     emp_id  org_id
1   John Mackenzie  TTT104   1
2   Raven Raid      TTT105   1
3   Albert Pinto    TTT106   2
4   Albert Pinto1   TTT119   2
5   Ram Raman       TTT108   2
6   Huge Jackman    TTT109   2
7   Peter Pan       TTT107   2
8   Albert Pinto2   TTT106   2
```

RESULT EXPECTED:

```
id  person_name     emp_id  count(org_id)
1   John Mackenzie  TTT104   2
2   Raven Raid      TTT105   2
3   Albert Pinto    TTT106   6
4   Albert Pinto1   TTT119   6
5   Ram Raman       TTT108   6
6   Huge Jackman    TTT109   6
7   Peter Pan       TTT107   6
8   Albert Pinto2   TTT106   6
```

As shown in the image I want my records to look in my velocity template:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

While collecting results, you The solution you are looking for is the following:

```
SELECT org_id, count(*)
FROM person
GROUP  BY org_id;
```

Basically with this query you are collecting the number of people working in each distinct org_id.

Result of the query is, then:

```
rg_id | count
-------------
1     | 2
2     | 6
```

Comment: I am trying to get records and in front of each record want a count of org_id.

Comment: Can you write in the question the result you expect from the data you declared?

Comment: I have updated my question with exact details How I want records to look.

Answer (score 0):

Execute query as below to solve the issue:

```
 SELECT p.person_name,
        p.emp_id,
        count(p.org_id) OVER w as org 
FROM person p WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY org_id);
```